# Error in BESTmcmc(y1, y2) : could not find function "BESTmcmc" in Rstudio

Tags: r, bayesian, t-test

I am learning how to use Bayesian t-tests using the R package "BEST", and practicing with the example on page two from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BEST/BEST.pdf

It looks like this:

```
## Comparison of two groups:
## =========================
y1 <- c(5.77, 5.33, 4.59, 4.33, 3.66, 4.48)
y2 <- c(3.88, 3.55, 3.29, 2.59, 2.33, 3.59)

# Run an analysis, takes up to 1 min.

BESTout <- BESTmcmc(y1, y2)
```

However, when I run the analysis, I get the following error and have no idea why:

Error in BESTmcmc(y1, y2) : could not find function "BESTmcmc".

I have successfully installed and loaded the package, so I am not sure why else I might be getting this error. I appreciate any help and insight I can get! I am using Rstudio by the way, if that makes any difference.

Comment: afaik it is not enough to simply install and load the package, but you also need jags. Did you get any error messages when running library("BEST") ?

Comment: Oh! you are right, I missed the error when loading the package. I have installed JAGS, and now it works. Thank you!!